# Hyperagent and apache not playing nice

Tags: javascript, apache, .htaccess, cross-domain

I'm calling an API through hyperagent.js on a site I transferred over from an old server.

Basically the script is calling an external URL from a HAL resource, and hyperagent is supposed to let me manipulate the data. The part of my code hyperagent is failing on is the following:

```
var api = new Hyperagent.Resource('http://my.api.com/');

api.fetch()   <--fails here
    .then(function (root) {  
       console.log('API root resolved:', root);
       apiRoot = root;
       return root.link('abf:brands-embed', { fields: 'abf:hotel.id,abf:hotel.lat,abf:hotel.lng'}).fetch();
})
.catch(function (err) {  <--caught here
  console.warn('Error fetching API root', err);
});
```

The err being returned is a javascript object with no meaningful message.

Since this script works on the old server, and my local machine, I'm pretty sure it is an apache server configuration issue, but I can't seem to locate what is wrong. Here is only part of my .htaccess file that deals with Cross Scripting:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff)$">
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

Shouldn't apply since the resource isn't one of the ones listed, right? Is there something I need to add to .htaccess to get everything to work? Some other way I can adjust hyperagent to get a more meaningful error message? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried just removing the `<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff)$">`/`</FilesMatch>` so that it just sends the header regardless?

Comment: In your browser devtools console there aren't any messages getting logged?

Comment: To be clear: Is that .htaccess snippet from the environment that is serving http://my.api.com/? You have config access to that environment?

Comment: @sideshowbarker yeah, nothing doing. API has been working on different page, looking into that.

Comment: @sideshowbarker I have dev tools, getting back a seemingly meaningless object from hyperagent. .htaccess file is on main domain, not API. Checking API's .htaccess file now

Comment: @sideshowbarker looks like the other page is curling the info, which works fine.